# Run java command from Google colab notebook

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a custom NER model on Google Colab. I installed Java on the VM and running the following command to call the NER jar file. But nothing seems to happen.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', '/content/gdrive/stanford-ner.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier', '-prop prop.txt'])
```

I see 1 on the screen but no trained Model.

I tried subprocess but the command doesn't execute.

```
import subprocess
cmd="java -cp /content/gdrive/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop prop.txt"
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

The error is

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'java -cp /content/gdrive/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop prop.txt': 'java -cp /content/gdrive/stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop prop.txt'

Answer (score 1):

From the python doc

> On Unix, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Hence, you are trying to execute a program named `"java -cp ..."` which certainly doesn't exist. You want to split `args` as an array of `["java", "-cp", ...]`.

But more simply, in Colab, you can invoke shell commands using `!`, hence you can  do

```
!java -cp ...
```

Also, make sure that `java` is in the `$PATH`.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I got a new way to run java code on colab. I was able to use the subprocess and cmd approach to run my code. the issue was of being in the wrong directory and executing the code.